# Simple sum not working in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to sum columns.

In my controller

```
         def index
          @performance_reports = PerformanceReport.all
         end
```

My error:

```
       undefined method `+' for #<PerformanceReport:0x4a55690>
74:         <td><%=  @performance_reports.sum(:clicks)%></td>
```

What is wrong ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try

```
 @performance_reports = PerformanceReport.select('*')
```

in views

```
<td><%=  @performance_reports.sum(:clicks)%></td>
```

basically  `PerformanceReport.all` will load whole table and return `Array` of `PerformanceReport` you can't chain queries on Array!!!

`PerformanceReport.select('*')` will return  `ActiveRecord::Relation` and you can chain any AR method on relation

i suggest you read rails lazing loading strategy [Lazy loading (will_paginate sample)](http://www.simonecarletti.com/blog/2011/04/understanding-ruby-and-rails-lazy-load-hooks/)  and  [Rails Query Interface](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html)

Awesome Rails

Answer (score 1):

This `sum` is an ActiveRecord method so you cant use it on already selected objects! What ypu can do:

```
PerformanceReport.sum(:clicks)
```

because then the Database is queried!